# Printing name off of file

Tags: python

```
f = glob.glob('/fulldirectory/*.txt')

for index, files in enumerate(f, 1):
    r = open(files)
    reader = csv.DictReader(r)
```

So I am trying to print off the actual name of a file as part of my analysis.

Each file in the directory above is named with this convention: R1.txt, R2.txt, R3.txt, etc.

At the moment I am simply using the enumerate function to print off the number - but this only works under the assumption that no files are missing in the directory.

EDIT:

I tried this, but it's not giving me quite what I want:

```
p = [int(s) for s in files if files.isdigit()]

print p

>[0,1]
>[0,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a simple `re.sub` to substitute the `.txt` to an empty string.

```
import re, glob
f = glob.glob('/fulldirectory/*.txt')
for file in f:
    print(re.sub('\.txt$', '', file))
    r = open(file)
    reader = csv.DictReader(r)
```

> In an ideal world I would print 'index', and on the first iteration, R01 would be printed. Then R02, etc.

If you like them to always be in order, do this instead to first sort the file names:

```
f = sorted(glob.glob('/fulldirectory/*.txt'))
```

If you only want to print the base name of the file, you can print this instead:

```
import os
print(re.sub('\.txt$', '', os.path.basename(file)))
```

Note: the other way suggested may not be very safe, because it's not recommended to use multiple splits on file names.

Here is a complete example with decent explanation that the OP requested:

```
import re, os, glob
file_list = glob.glob('/fulldirectory/*.txt') # get the list of file names that ends in .txt
f = sorted(file_list, key = lambda x: int(re.findall('\d+\.txt$',os.path.basename(x))[0]))
    # 1               2     3          8  4          5            6                   7
for file in f:
    print(re.sub('\.txt$', '', file))
          # 9
    # do your stuff....
```

1. The `sorted()` function is used to sort the list of file names then store it into f (f is the sorted version of file_list)
2. the `key` argument is a function that accepts an argument and outputs a sortable object(ie. `str`, `int`, `list`...), it is used to define the key it's sorting with
3. lambda is an anonymous function that accepts argument 'x', this works the same way as a `def NoName(x): return something`
4. Use `re.findall` to find all substrings that matches the regex, in this case, there only should one one match [ie. `'abc123.txt'` will return `[123]`]
5. `'\d+\.txt$'` is a regex, `\d+` - any number repeating one or more times, `\.` is a regular dot `.` theres a `\` in front because normally in regex, a `.` has the special meaning which it represents any character, the `\` escapes it, making it only a regular `.`, `txt` is a string to match at that given location, and `$` is the symbol indicating it to match only at the *end* of the string.
6. `os.path.basename()` is used to retrieve the basename (the final part of the path [ie. `'abc123.txt'` of `'\a\b\c\abc123.txt'`])
7. since `re.findall()` always return a list so to retrieve the only match will involve using [0] (ie. `['123',][0]` => `'123'`)
8. because the data retrieved is a string, have to use the int() to change it to an `int` for comparing. The int is what got passed to `key` in #2.
9. `re.sub('\.txt$', '', file)` the first argument is a regex, the second argument is the string to replace it to, the third argument is the string that need replacing (ie. `re.sub('a', '', 'banana')`=>`bnn` because it replaces every `a` with nothing) check #5 for more information about the regex

If you need any more clarification, tell me

Alternative method of importing is this:

```
import glob
from re import sub, findall
from os.path import basename
file_list = glob.glob('/fulldirectory/*.txt') # get the list of file names that ends in .txt
f = sorted(file_list, key = lambda x: int(findall('\d+\.txt$',basename(x))[0]))

for file in f:
    print(sub('\.txt$', '', file))

    # do your stuff....
```

helpful links:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a method which takes the digits from the directory and saves them into a list. This works - but it only works under the assumption that no other numbers are present in the directory, which isn't ideal. I'm going to switch to your method though. I don't fully understand how it works though.

Comment: Could you explain the basename method? I'm not exactly sure what a lot of that code is actually doing.

Comment: A hint: sorted method has a key parameter in which you can a pass a function to tell it how to sort, if you only wanted to sort with the last two numbers you can do:  `f = sorted(glob.glob('/fulldirectory/*.txt'),key=lambda x: os.path.basename(x).rstrip(".txt")[-2:])`

Comment: I'll get back to you with the explanation later

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. I'm going to go with the regular expression method above. However, I'm not sure what re.sub() actually is.

Comment: It stands for substitute, which will substitute only the ending .txt with blank string. It's quite useful actually

Comment: Thanks. That's cool, I'll need to look more into that. It works which is good

Comment: What does the \ and $ represent?

Comment: I'm writing an explaination right now, will be done soon

Comment: Okay thanks! Also, just wondering if it's suitable to do 'from re import sub'

Comment: yes, you can do that too, same with `from os.path import basename`

Comment: @Polar_Py you can check my explanations now

Comment: Wow thanks for the info. I'll take a good look over it all tomorrow when I wake up.

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure about the $ symbol? It works fine without using it

Comment: $ makes sure it only matches in the end of string, it's a good habit to do so, for example, if you have a file named `ab.txtc.txt` If $ is not present, it will become `abc`, but you probably want `ab.txtc` only getting rid of the last .txt, it's just a small tweak

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just go like this:

```
f = glob.glob('/fulldirectory/*.txt')

for files in f:
    print files.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, but I am also trying to print the actual filename. The above code prints the entire directory as well. Is there a way to get around that?